# GDB breakpoint doesn't stop

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

My goal is to figure out the address space of `str_main`, but gdb skips over my breakpoint.

How do I find its address location?

I have a simple c program, `stack.c`:

```
....
19 int main(int argc, char **argv[])
20 {
21    char str_main[517];
22    FILE *badfile;
23 
24    badfile = fopen("badfile","r");
....
```

When I enter gdb I set a breakpoint at line 21. However, when I run the debugger, I get the following message:

```
Breakpoint 1, main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3d4) at stack.c:24
24            badfile = fopen("badfile","r");
```

Comment: Line 22 is not really an executable line in the compiled binary. But what is the problem? Stopping at line 24 is perfectly ok for what you want to do. What do you think you can see in the debugger on line 22 that you can't on line 24? That is, you have a non-problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDB wont stop on declarations without default value.

Even after reaching 24, you can still print the address.

```
p /s str_main
```